# What would explain Spring Boot behaviour change between jars and plain directories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I got a Spring based (boot 2.4.13 & integration 5.4.12) project and aside it another Spring based project that uses some of its code.

My problem is that using jars of the first project with a main class from the second, the run fails with a missing dependency diagnostic.

Funny enough, if I unzip the jars, each in its (new clean) directory and replace its place in the classpath with the unjarred/unzipped directory, it falls into functioning, not failing with missing dependency.

I checked that unzip -l and find in the unjarred top directory both list .class files in the same order. Same thing for *.properties files that are not pom.properties.

So I can not explain the difference in behaviour by plain order between classes nor configuration properties files.

So I wonder : is there something done differently (and on purpose) by Spring when classes come from a jar or could it be a lack of luck that directories and pom.properties files order has mattered ?